# component drag and drop

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, air, adobe

I have created a Box component and inside it I have more then 2-3 labels placed. I need to drag the whole box component and move to different place at canvas. Technically Box type is a container type but I need to keepit all the labels inside and want to move it. Is there any way we can do that ? Thanks for any ideas.

UPDATED : Can we create any external component that allow us to drag the main box ?

Comment: have you tried container.startDrag()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement drag-n-drop on the container component.  For a great guide to drag-n-drop in Flex 4, see the following tutorials by Justin Shacklette:

[Drag-and-Drop in Flex 4](http://saturnboy.com/2009/08/drag-and-drop-flex-4/)

[Drag-and-Drop Revisited](http://saturnboy.com/2010/12/drag-and-drop-revisited/)

Comment: i was thinking about some external button that allow the box to move/drag/drop not the component itself.